# In Android devices, is the fingerprint template generated by the vendor-specific library or the sensor?

Tags: android, fingerprint

My understanding based on the online resources is that there is a vendor-specific fingerprint library running in the TEE which is responsible for communicating to the fingerprint sensor hardware as well as enrollment, matching, ... of fingerprints.

What is unclear to me is what the sensor's output is? Does it generate the fingerprint template, or it sends just the raw fingerprint data to the library and the template is generated by the library?

Comment: just adding this as a comment because i'm definitely not sure of this, but your question might not find answers here because i'm not sure if this is actually a question related to development or code, it might rather find answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com.), but again, i'm not sure

Comment: @a_local_nobody this is a question that can be answered from somebody who can read source code, so well placed on stackoverflow (android enthusiasts is for usage of android devices, not for developers) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/master/biometrics/fingerprint/2.1/IBiometricsFingerprint.hal